# C++ WinApi Качество рисования

Tags: c++

Если например рисовать круг на окне, то он получается нечетким, как рисовать/рендерить более точно неровные примитивы?

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос ваш код и скриншот, а то непонятно :)

Comment: @gil9red, не, в данном случае как раз вопрос понятен. Нужен антиалиас. И чувак, который умеет его на WinApi. Я думаю кто-нибудь скоро ответит.

Comment: Если речь идёт о готовых средствах, то можно использовать GDI+, Cairo, или http://antigrain.com/index.html

Comment: Что значит четкие и не четкие?

Comment: WinAPI сам по себе не умеет рисовать круги и прочее. Для рисования используются какие-либо графические библиотеки, например, GDI или GDI+ (они сильно разные). Что именно используется у вас?